# Please how do I interpret the code below?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On my CloudFormation template, I have a parameter called WPDirectory.

Please how do I interpret the code below?

```
"# make site directory\n",
"if [ ! -d /var/www/wordpress/", !Ref WPDirectory, " ]; then\n",                    
"   mkdir -p /var/www/wordpress/", !Ref WPDirectory, "\n",
"\n",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ref` is an intrinsic function in Cloudformation template. It returns the value of the parameter. `!Ref WPDirectory` will return the value of the `WPDirectory` parameter which is passed as an input to the cloudformation template.

[Refer this link for documentation on ref functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html)

The code you shared will be executed as shell script probably on an EC2 instance as UserData. In this script, it is just checking if "/var/www/wordpress/WPDirectory-name" directory exists, if not it creates the mentioned directory

Comment: Thank you Suraj. What I dont understand is how the "if [ ! -d /var/www/wordpress/" and  "mkdir -p /var/www/wordpress/" script relates to the WPDirectory

Comment: The code you shared is partial but having worked extensively on Cloudformation, I think I can interpret the missing code. The code you shared will be executed as shell script probably on an EC2 instance as UserData. In this script, it is just checking if "/var/www/wordpress/<WPDirectory-name>" directory exists, if not it creates the mentioned directory

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Suraj! That is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you. It can help others too.